# GWT uibinder - how to specify such a simple layout?

Tags: gwt, layout, uibinder

I'm using GWT 2.5.1 with uibinder xml for specifying ui layouts.

Being a newbie in this, can't figure out how to specify even a simple layout:

[image: i-want-this]

I want the [Somelabel:] and [Button] to take the minimal required place, and [Textbox] to occupy the rest. Tried different approaches: placing them to HorizontalPanel, FlowPanel, even DockLayoutPanel. None of them satisfy my requirements: HorizontalPanel just divides parent container to three equal parts, FlowPanel gives no respect to element width, DockLayoutPanel wants me to manually calculate and specify the width of [Somelabel:] and [Button] and still doesn't work at all.

That is the basic ui layout task and I can't believe that GWT does not have a way to specify what I want without manual pixelwidth calculation. Most different UI tools have the simple way to specify it.

this lays them in equal cells:

```
    <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
        <g:Label>Somelabel:</g:Label>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="someTextBox"/>
        <g:Button ui:field="someButton" text="Button"/>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
```

[image: horizontal-panel]

this lays them in a weird way (whether "float: left" specified for label or not; whether "float: right" specified for button or not):

```
    <g:FlowPanel width="100%">
        <g:Label>Somelabel:</g:Label>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="someTextBox"/>
        <g:Button ui:field="someButton" text="Button"/>
    </g:FlowPanel>
```

[image: flow-panel]

this wants me to specify pixels but doesn't even display them:

```
    <g:DockLayoutPanel width="100%" height="90">
        <g:east size="30"><g:Label>Somelabel:</g:Label></g:east>
        <g:center><g:TextBox ui:field="someTextBox"/></g:center>
        <g:west size="50"><g:Button ui:field="someButton" text="Button"/></g:west>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

[no image because it doesn't display anything]

I'm kinda stuck because the only kind-of-working xml is the HorizontalPanel one and it does not do what I want.

**UP:** added screenshots and tried "float:" css styles (which didn't change anything).

**UP2:** got the picture I wanted using LayoutPanel and specifying pixelwidth of each layer.

```
    <g:LayoutPanel width="100%" height="40px">
        <g:layer width="100px" left="0">
            <g:Label>Somelabel:</g:Label>
        </g:layer>
        <g:layer left="100px" right="200px">
            <g:TextBox ui:field="someTextBox"/>
        </g:layer>
        <g:layer width="200px" right="0">
            <g:Button ui:field="someButton" text="Button"/>
        </g:layer>
    </g:LayoutPanel>
```

But the xml looks ugly, forces me to calculate pixels manually, and to specify each width in two places. Can I somehow leave the pixelwidth calculations to framework and just specify "place it there and give it minimum place it wants"?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the `GWT` docs [here][1] it mentions your exact problem. Try using `FlowPanel` with `float : left` `CSS` property as specified.

**EDIT :**
This worked for me

Ui-Binder

```
<g:FlowPanel width="100%" addStyleNames="myTable">
    <g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="myTableRow">
        <g:Label addStyleNames="myTableLabel">Somelabel:</g:Label>
        <g:FlowPanel width="100%" addStyleNames="myTableCell">
            <g:TextBox ui:field="someTextBox" addStyleNames="myTableInput"/>
        </g:FlowPanel>
        <g:Button ui:field="someButton" text="Button" addStyleNames="myTableButton"/>
    </g:FlowPanel>
</g:FlowPanel>
```

CSS :

```
.myTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

}

.myTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.myTableLabel {
    display: table-cell;
}

.myTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.myTableInput {
width: 100%;    
}

.myTableButton {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: So i do not specify the layout in a ui.xml-file, but specify it in css instead. Please tell me how to refer to the label and the button from webapp's css? Should i assign some IDs to them?

Comment: Thanks for telling about CSS. It didn't help a bit though. Updated question with screenshots.

Comment: @AndreyRegentov i don't think what you are tying to achieve is possible with parent set to 100% width. If it would have been a a fixed width yes might have achieved using sometextbox.getelement().getstyle().setwidth(); with calculating width as parentWidth - labelWidth-ButtonWidth

Comment: @AndreyRegentov check updated answer.. the culprit was the textBox. it had to be nested in a div

Comment: Also use white-space : nowrap CSS for the Label in case the Label is split with a space...

Comment: Don't know the reason, but your exact code renders in my case to http://i.stack.imgur.com/zpRZG.png (all elements stacked vertically) whether css is specified or not.

Comment: are you adding to a root Panel this ui binder try hard refresh ctrl + f5

Comment: Maybe the reason is that the discussed layout is a part of other layout (VerticalPanel width="600px") which is a part of another layout. I can't affect non-my parts.

Comment: But when i cleaned browser cache explicitly, it seems to display differently

Comment: Like here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/D72TO.png note that the textbox lays over the button. Thanks anyway for effort. Will not mark it as answer, but the bounty is yours.

Comment: yes that may be the cause(Vertical Panel..as it displays everything in one single vertical column)..try playing with some CSS and you might get what you want..and thanks..yes i know the answer needs tweaking per requirement...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45351/discussion-between-onkar-and-andrey-regentov)